# Node Webpack eval() sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am struggling setting up a Node project with TypeScript.
My workflow is: I run a Node script using nodemon. The node script creates a webpack compiler instance and sets the filesystem to MemoryFS. The webpack config includes loaders for TypeScript and Babel.
After webpack has finished compiling, if there are errors, I throw then, if not I fetch the result with MemoryFS and eval() it to run the code.

All of that works fine. But I tried to add sourcemaps support. I added a banner plugin in webpack which adds 'source-map-support'. In webpack, I set the devtool to 'source-map'. In tsconfig.json, I have the sourcemaps option enabled. In the src/index.ts I just throw an error, and at runtime Node doesn't tell me where did the error occur. (the sourcemap)

But if I run webpack normally, and then I run it using `node dist/bundle.js`. It is working.

I think there is a problem because of me using eval() to run the compiled output.

src/index.ts:

```
console.log('Hello world');

throw new Error('not');
```

build.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MemoryFS = require('memory-fs');

const fs = new MemoryFS();

const config = require('./webpack.config');

const compiler = webpack(config);

compiler.outputFileSystem = fs;

compiler.run((err, stats) => {
    console.clear();

    const jsonStats = stats.toJson();

    if(jsonStats.errors.length > 0 || jsonStats.warnings.length > 0)
        return console.log(jsonStats.warning, jsonStats.errors);

    const result = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'bundle.js')).toString();

    eval(result);
});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + '/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'babel-loader' },
                    { loader: 'ts-loader' },
                    { loader: 'tslint-loader' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    target: 'node',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            raw: true,
            entryOnly: false,
            banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();'
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

After running webpack normally and executing the code (`webpack && node dist\bundle.js`, as expected):

```
C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\dist\webpack:\src\index.ts:3
throw new Error('not');
    ^
Error: not
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\dist\webpack:\src\index.ts:3:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\dist\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap a6ba0885ca7e8b14ee63:19:1)
    at C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\dist\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap a6ba0885ca7e8b14ee63:62:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\dist\bundle.js:67:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
```

Running it using `build.js`:

```
Hello world
Error: not
    at Object.eval (eval at compiler.run (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\build.js:23:5), <anonymous>:75:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (eval at compiler.run (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\build.js:23:5), <anonymous>:21:30)
    at eval (eval at compiler.run (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\build.js:23:5), <anonymous>:64:18)
    at eval (eval at compiler.run (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\build.js:23:5), <anonymous>:67:10)
    at compiler.run (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\build.js:23:5)
    at emitRecords.err (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\graph\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `eval` to run the code, Node will have no idea about the source map. Perhaps you can try to run a child node process instead of using `eval` to run the result, or is there any reason you're using `eval`? See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: I know what you mean, but can you give me an example? I tried using `child_process.execSync(\`node ${result}\`);` and still, no success. I just get the code outputed in the console

Comment: you have to actually run the file I think - then node knows to look for the source map in `bundle.js.map`.

`child_process.spawn('node', [DIST_DIR + '/bundle.js']);` maybe?

Comment: No, doesn't work. Just nothing prints. I think that's because I use MemoryFS for the webpack output and therefore I cannot run it directly using a normal path. I could have used the normal `fs` but I don't want  to have outputs to a directory when developing.

Comment: Ah you're right, the child process can't access the files from MemoryFS. Can't you save to `os.tmpdir()`? https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir

Comment: Maybe there's a way to execute a child process inline? Like `node <the compiled output>`? I tried to do that for a simple case `node console.log(5)` or `node "console.log(5)"`. Do you know if there's a way to execute Node commands inline? If there is, do you think the sourcemaps will be available?

Comment: You can run something inline with `node -e "console.log(5)"` for example, but in your case the source map will then also not be available.
Again, what you are doing is an unusual way of doing things. Build tools usually just write things to the file system. There might be a way to manually load your source map somehow with https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support - `require('source-map-support').install({
  retrieveSourceMap: ...` if you really must.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is a very unusual way of doing things xD. Of course, I prefer to have webpack compile to `MemoryFS`. But you can't have it all. It's not that bad. Thanks